Using pointers to refer to tuple element data: are pointers guaranteed to remain valid during tuple lifetime?
My question
I have a tuple consisting of user defined types that all have the same double member:
template<int N>
struct foo
{
    int value = 3 * N; // Just using mock default value here.
};

using my_tuple = std::tuple<foo<0>, foo<1>, foo<2>, foo<3>>;

In short, I want to be able to use raw pointers to refer to the value member of each element in the tuple, and to store these raw_pointers in a map/vector, so that the values can be iterated in a somewhat efficient manner. However, I am not sure what guarantees there are about those pointers remaining valid over the entire lifetime of the tuple.
More precisely, my question is whether there is any guarantee for this in the standard; either explicit or as a consequence of other constraints.
For example, say I create a tuple and record the pointers to the elements' value in a vector:
my_tuple mt;
std::array<int*, std::tuple_size_v<my_tuple>> ptr_arr = get_pointers_to_element_value(mt); // Impl below.

for (int* val_ptr : ptr_arr)
{
    std::cout << *val_ptr << '\n'; // Prints 0, 3, 6, 9
}

// Use and modify mt. For example, change an element's value.
std::get<foo<2>>(mt).value = 11;

for (int* val_ptr : ptr_arr)
{
    std::cout << *val_ptr << '\n'; // Prints 0, 3, 11, 9
}

This compiles and appears to work as desired. However, it is not clear to me what guarantees I have that the pointers in the vector will remain valid so long as the tuple stays alive. For example, it is possible for a std::vector to be resized upon adding new elements, which results in any raw pointers pointing to those elements becoming invalid.
I want to know if there are any similar scenarios that could invalidate the pointer's to a tuple's elements' members.
EDIT
I decided to forward some of the comments of @Gene's answer to here, as it has information that I think is close to answering my question. Namely:

In tuple, you are accessing members of the class, and just like any other class, it cannot change the address of its members. Any non-static members of any class have the same addresses as long as the class is alive.

If this can be guaranteed, then it can be guaranteed that a pointer to the element value cannot be invalidated for the lifetime of the tuple.
However, I think the only point of uncertainly is whether the standard specifies the elements of tuple as member objects. For a pair, the standard (or at least the c++20 draft isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf ) (see 20.4.2) specify the elements as member variables, whereas I'm failing to find anything similar on the tuple's elements (20.5.3).
/EDIT
Further context
While the previous section pertains to the particular question I'm asking, this section serves to give additional context, namely, the more general problem I am trying to solve. While the question here isn't about solving this general problem (and I could very well be asking how to solve problem X when I really want to be solving problem Y!), I've included this section to clarify my intent, and just in case certain solutions make more sense.
My most general goal is to write a static library that will involve templated types that can be multiplied together to yield other types.
To that end, I want to provide the user a convenient way to iterate over the value of each tuple element during runtime:
my_tuple mt;
for (int val : mt)
{
    std::cout << val << '\n';
}

The syntactic sugar of the ranged seems particularly desirable.
Normally, iterating over a tuple isn't feasible, since the elements are generally of different types. However, it is plausible in this case: we are iterating over the value of each element, as opposed to the element itself, and all the types comprising the tuple are guaranteed to have a value member of type int.
So, I'm looking to implement an iterator class, my_iter, and this should be able to return a reference to the element value to which it is indicating. That is, we need to be able to query an element value from the tuple at any runtime index. Using std::get<N>(mt) directly isn't going to work here, since N would need to be known at compile time.
The current solution is to compute from the tuple an array of pointers to each of the tuple elements' value member:
static auto get_pointers_to_element_value(my_tuple& mt)
{
    return std::apply(
        [](auto&&... foos) {
            std::array<int*, sizeof...(foos)> arr{ &(foos.value) ... };
            return arr;
        }
    , mt);
}

Then, we can obtain the nth tuple element value via
int* ptr_to_el_val = get_pointers_to_element_value(mt).at(n); 

So, the iterator might be implemented as
class my_iter
{
public:
    my_iter() noexcept = default;
    my_iter(std::size_t ind, my_tuple* mt) noexcept : ind{ ind }, mt{ mt } {}
    int& operator*() const { return *get_pointers_to_element_value(*mt).at(ind); };
    my_iter& operator++() noexcept { ++ind; return *this; }
    my_iter operator++(int) noexcept{ my_iter tmp{ *this }; ++(*this); return tmp; }
    friend static bool operator==(my_iter left_tab, my_iter right_tab) noexcept = default;
private:
    std::size_t ind = 0;
    my_tuple* mt = nullptr;
};

This seems to work nicely. However, it does mean that every time the iterator is dereferenced, we have to compute the array of pointers, turning it into a O(n) operation. Ideally, I'd like to be able to store the vector of pointers, say, on the iterator, to avoid this recomputation. So, something like this:
class my_iter
{
public:
    my_iter() noexcept = default;
    my_iter(std::size_t ind, my_tuple* mt) noexcept : ind{ ind }, mt{ mt }
    {
        if (ind < std::tuple_size_v<my_tuple>)
        {
            auto arr = get_pointers_to_element_value(*mt);
            this->ptr_vec.insert(this->ptr_vec.begin(), arr.begin(), arr.end());
        }
    }
    int& operator*() const { return *(this->ptr_vec.at(ind)); };
    my_iter& operator++() noexcept { ++ind; return *this; }
    my_iter operator++(int) noexcept { my_iter tmp{ *this }; ++(*this); return tmp; }
    friend static bool operator==(my_iter left_tab, my_iter right_tab) noexcept
    {
        return (left_tab.ind == right_tab.ind) && (left_tab.mt == right_tab.mt);
    };
private:
    std::size_t ind = 0;
    my_tuple* mt = nullptr;
    std::vector<int*> ptr_vec;
};

Now we only need to compute the vector of pointers once (at iterator construction), and then iterator dereferencing should take O(1) time. However, this change also assumes the pointers in ptr_vec remain valid for the lifetime of the tuple.
A fair point might be: why not simply use a vector instead of a tuple if you need to be iterating during runtime? The reason is that my_tuple will actually be a class template allowing any combinations of different foo types. It is important that each foo instance of the template corresponds to a unique class.
Complete example
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

template<int N>
struct foo
{
    int value = 3 * N;
};

using my_tuple = std::tuple<foo<0>, foo<1>, foo<2>, foo<3>>;

static auto get_pointers_to_element_value(my_tuple& mt)
{
    return std::apply(
        [](auto&&... foos) {
            std::array<int*, sizeof...(foos)> arr{ &(foos.value) ... };
            return arr;
        }
    , mt);
}

class my_iter
{
public:
    my_iter() noexcept = default;
    my_iter(std::size_t ind, my_tuple* mt) noexcept : ind{ ind }, mt{ mt }
    {
        if (ind < std::tuple_size_v<my_tuple>)
        {
            auto arr = get_pointers_to_element_value(*mt);
            this->ptr_vec.insert(this->ptr_vec.begin(), arr.begin(), arr.end());
        }
    }
    int& operator*() const { return *(this->ptr_vec.at(ind)); };
    my_iter& operator++() noexcept { ++ind; return *this; }
    my_iter operator++(int) noexcept { my_iter tmp{ *this }; ++(*this); return tmp; }
    friend static bool operator==(my_iter left_tab, my_iter right_tab) noexcept
    {
        return (left_tab.ind == right_tab.ind) && (left_tab.mt == right_tab.mt);
    };
private:
    std::size_t ind = 0;
    my_tuple* mt = nullptr;
    std::vector<int*> ptr_vec;
};

static my_iter begin(my_tuple& mt) { return my_iter{ 0, &mt }; }
static my_iter end(my_tuple& mt) { return my_iter{ std::tuple_size_v<my_tuple>, &mt }; }

int main()
{
    my_tuple mt;

    for (int val : mt)
    {
        std::cout << val << '\n'; // 0, 3, 6, 9
    }

    std::get<foo<2>>(mt).value = 11;

    for (int val : mt)
    {
        std::cout << val << '\n'; // 0, 3, 11, 9
    }
}


You can iterate a tuple at run time using compile time code.  You can make a for_each function for your tuple and use it almost like you have with: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9882c2277b3c4143

@NathanOliver That is a great approach that can also be adapted for iterations/functions that modify each value. The only minor downside is that it trades out the nice syntax of the ranged for-loop. The for_each function is still very concise, but, as I'm writing this code as a static library (this detail now added to question), you can't beat the ranged for-loop syntax for brevity, and won't look unfamiliar to users that aren't familiar with lambdas and constexpr.


My goal is to be able to iterate over the value of each tuple element
during runtime.

Iterating over the tuple elements can be done in different ways. You don't need to create an iterator for that, which won't work if data types are different anyway. Moreover it can be implemented as a constexpr function iterating at compile time, having no run-time overhead. Here is a possible solution, which works for multiple tuples (why not, implementation is basically the same):
constexpr auto tuple_foreach(auto&& transform_fn, /*tuple_like*/ auto&& t, /*tuple_like*/ auto&& ...ts)
    requires ((sizeof ...(ts) == 0 ||
    ((std::tuple_size<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>>{} == std::tuple_size<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(ts)>>{})
    && ...)) && std::invocable<decltype(transform_fn), decltype(std::get<0>(t)), decltype(std::get<0>(ts))...>)
{
    auto get_n = [&]<std::size_t N>(std::index_sequence<N>)
    {
        transform_fn(std::get<N>(std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)), std::get<N>(std::forward<decltype(ts)>(ts))...);
    };

    auto get_all = [&]<std::size_t ...N>(std::index_sequence<N...>)
    {
        (get_n(std::index_sequence<N>{}),...);
    };
    
    constexpr auto size = std::tuple_size<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>>{};
    get_all(std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
}

Here is demo.

Sorry, I wasn't clear with my question; I've hopefully clarified this now in my post. I mainly want to know about the conditions of validity of pointers to tuples. For my case, iterators are preferable as I'm writing this as part of a static library; an iterator is there for the user's convenience. Also, in my case we can assume that the tuple types have data of the same type, so an iterator is still appropriate.

@Involute -- there is nothing special about pointers to the elements of the tuple, they are valid as long as the tuple is alive.

That's what I was hoping to hear, but is there any standard/source that says that? It might be true when I'm compiling on my own machine, but since I'm planning to add this as a static library, I just need some assurance that this will work for any user.

@Involute -- Standard doesn't say anything specific about tuple because it doesn't need to say anything, you can take a pointer to a member of a class. Any pointer to anything is dereferenceable only as long as the object it points to is alive.

It is true the pointer of anything is true so long as that something lives, but the tuple is responsible for the lifetime of its members/elements, not us, so we can't necessarily be sure. An example of this is a vector: a pointer to one of its elements is invalidated if your resize() the vector. How can we be sure something similar doesn't happen for tuple?

@Involute -- vector and tuple are not alike. In tuple, you are accessing members of the class, and just like any other class, it cannot change the address of its members. Any non-static members of any class have the same addresses as long as the class is alive. In vector, you are not accessing members of the class, you are accessing dynamically allocated memory, managed by vector.

I see, that makes sense. The last piece of the puzzle is how can we be certain the tuple elements are actually stored as members on the tuple class? For a pair, the standard (or at least the c++20 draft https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4860.pdf )  (see 20.4.2) specify the elements as member variables, whereas I'm failing to find anything similar on the tuple's elements (20.5.3). If you could clarify this in your answer, I'd be more than happy to mark it as accepted.

To answer your first question, do pointers to elements of a std::tuple remain valid as long as the tuple is alive? Yes, always. If you have a pointer to a member of a vector, however, that pointer will be invalidated when the vector resizes.
If I understand the second part to your question correctly, you want to take the addresses of the value member of some arbitrary instances of foo<N> and store them in a std::vector<int*> without constructing a new tuple each time you iterate. You can pretty easily do this with std::make_integer_sequence.
namespace detail {
    template<typename Tuple, size_t... Idxs>
    auto convertTupleToVecImpl(Tuple& tuple, std::index_sequence<Idxs...> idxs) {
        std::vector vec{ &std::get<Idxs>(tuple).value... };
        return vec;
    }
}

template<typename Tuple>
auto convertTupleToVec(Tuple& tuple) {
    return detail::convertTupleToVecImpl(tuple, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>>());
}

template<int N>
struct Foo { int value = N; };

int main() {
    std::tuple<Foo<0>, Foo<1>, Foo<5>> tuple;

    auto vec = convertTupleToVec(tuple);

    //prints 0 1 5
    for (const auto& elem : vec) {
        std::println("{}", *elem);
    }
}


I would also strongly expect that in any tuple implementation the pointers will stay valid throughout its lifetime. However, what I think the asker wanted (and what interests me as well) is whether there is any guarantee for this in the standard; either explicit or as a consequence of other constraints.

@Wutz That's right, I couldn't have said it better. I'll update and clarify my question to reflect this.

The trick is that the lifetime of the tuple may end (and new tuples be constructed) if the vector reallocates.

if you want to convert tuple then std::array is a natural choice, can be constexpr and done at compile time.

@Wutz -- there is nothing special about tuple, it's just a class containing values, the Standard doesn't need to state any tuple guarantees.

@Dúthomhas I'm not sure I follow. Even if the vector reallocates, surely that shouldn't impact the lifetime of the tuple. The vector only contains raw pointers, the addresses of those pointers will change, but the pointed data should be unaffected

@Involute My bad. I seem to have been having a hard time reading carefully lately. You are right: it is not an issue if the vector is just pointers to the tuples.

for the sake of somebody, who might be reading this in the future, here is the simplest one-liner conversion to array: std::apply([](auto...v){ return std::array{v.value ...}; }, my_tuple); https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5ssfMf11n

@Gene am I understanding correctly that you're saying the default assumption is that pointers won't be invalidated and the standard will explicitly state if a class deviates from this? For example, for vector it is explicitly stated that references might be invalidated by certain operations. If it's not stated otherwise, then references/pointers will stay valid. Is that what you're saying?

@Wutz -- I don't want to repeat the same things in two threads, see my comments below.
